# Why did Harry cast Sectumsempra on Snape?

Tags: harry-potter

The common reason given to Harry not using Avada Kedavra is that Harry is not a killer. Clearly it's not the fear of Azkaban as he casts Crucio and Imperio.

However, Harry did know that Sectumsempra was a killing spell. (Would probably be considered an Unforgivable Curse, if the Minister found out about it, and was not because only Snape and Harry actually knew the spell). And he still tried to hit Snape with it, knowing that he would kill him.

Doesn't this go against Harry using a disarming spell to fight Voldemort?

Comment: Literally disarming, in this case.

Comment: Don't think it's a killing spell (at least not directly) as Malfoy didn't die when Harry used it on him

Comment: Ummm, Sectumsempra isn't a Killing Curse.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix he didn't die because of snape. as the spell creator, he knew the "counter" spell. otherwise malfoy would have died

Comment: @Shreedhar
the spell translates to something like "cut/amputated forever" (assuming latin translates literally to my language) which makes one bleed to death. how is that not a killing spell?

Comment: @raiton I agree, but Sectumsempra (according to your translation) amputates/cuts someone. Unless the person bleeds out, it is not necessarily a killing curse (bleeding out killed the person, not the curse). If so, then every curse is a potential Killing Curse. One can use *Expelliarmus* to throw his opponent off a cliff. Or *stupefy* an opponent and drown him.

Comment: It isn't only Snape who can counter the spell — Mrs Weasley does as well, when it's been used on George.

Comment: @Shreedhar once hit with the spell you'll keep bleeding. that's the effect. unless it is aimed to only make one cut, like George's ear, it will keep filling your body with cuts

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine do you happen to have a quote that proves Mrs Weasly does know the counterspell? and why did he used a ton of bandages if she indeed knew the spell to fix it?

Comment: "Mrs Weasley had staunched his bleeding now, and by the lamplight Harry saw a clean, gaping hole where George's ear had been". Fallen Warrior, HBP. It doesn't prove it's "the" counterspell (if it has a specific one, I don't think there's enough evidence to know), but it proves she can counter it.

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine she used bandages because snape only did 1 cut. snape never wanted to kill anyone. he used it cirurgically like a single slash sword.
the spell in full power will fill your body with cuts. harry used it with no training and without even knowing what it was and filled Malfoy's body with cuts. So imagine what a trained snape could do with it.
hence the sempra. forever. you'll be cut forever

Comment: I can't see any quotation that says she uses bandages anywhere (but I've only skim read my copy). I presumed she'd stopped the bleeding magically — it definitely isn't bandaged in the above quotation because you can see the wound, and it's mentioned as being a dark hole in the wedding chapter too, again indicating it's not covered. (If this is too off-topic, feel free to move it to chat somebody who can!)

Comment: @BeginTheBeguine you can see it bandaged on the movies. it's an important thing and JKR would never accept that change. like she never accepted other important pieces of plot.
Snape created the spell and the counter "Vulnera Sanentur" (vulnus - wound, sanare - to heal). Only snape knows the counter as he's the one who created it. it also has to be casted 3 times for maximum effect (like he did in the movie)
the book doesn't say anything about magic being used to stop the bleeding
https://harry-potter-compendium.fandom.com/wiki/Vulnera_Sanentur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119246/discussion-between-beginthebeguine-and-raiton).

Answer (score 9):

Harry already tried casting the highly illegal Cruciatus Curse twice against Snape earlier in the fight. Snape mocked him, saying he lacked the ability to cast Unforgivable Curses.

> "Cruc - "
>
> But Snape parried the curse, knocking Harry backward off his feet before he could complete it; Harry rolled over and scrambled back up again as the huge Death Eater behind him yelled, "Incendio!" Harry heard an explosive bang and a dancing orange light spilled over all of them: Hagrid's house was on fire.
>
> "Fang's in there, yer evil - !" Hagrid bellowed.
>
> "Cruc -" yelled Harry for the second time, aiming for the figure ahead illuminated in the dancing firelight, but Snape blocked the spell again. Harry could see him sneering.
>
> "No Unforgivable Curses from you, Potter!" he shouted over the rushing of the flames, Hagrid's yells, and the wild yelping of the trapped Fang. "You haven't got the nerve or the ability."

Harry, the narration tells us, “felt no fear at all, but only rage and contempt.” He wanted Snape to hurt. He wanted him to hurt quite badly. He didn’t know how to cast the Killing Curse, but he cast the worst curse he knew he could perform. It’s likely in the moment he was aware he was attempting to kill Snape, or very least that his death was likely to result from his actions. He was an angry, 16-year-old boy who watched one of his worst enemies betray and murder his dearest mentor, while he sat there powerless to act.

A year earlier, when Harry had also run down an opponent who had killed a man he loved and cast Unforgivable Curses, he was pretty explicit about his intentions.

> “SHE KILLED SIRIUS!” bellowed Harry. “SHE KILLED HIM — I’LL KILL HER!”

You are correct that this goes against Harry later using the disarming charm to beat Voldemort. But in both instances he was a young man under severe emotional turmoil. Harry matures and learns to deal with his grief more mature ways, and extend mercy to his enemies. That’s character growth, kids!

Comment: Harry learns about the killing curse in GoF. Mad Eye (well the imposter version) teaches them about the 3 unforgivables

Comment: Also, as fake Mad-Eye said- "*Using the Avada Kedavra isn't so easy, at most you kids could do is give each other nose-bleeds*" (paraphrased).

Comment: @SpacePhoenix One thing is knowing about the curse, another entirely different thing is knowing how to cast it.

Comment: @TenthJustice so it's just character growth? Seems odd to me that such in a small time frame one would go from trying to kill someone who killed 1 professor, to not trying to kill someone who's responsible for all the deaths in the series including the said professor.
ps. how did Voldemort die with expeliarmus? also, was harry trying to kill Voldemort? cause if he was, then again, I see no reason now to use a killing spell (he would have had to practice it though, but since it's a stronger spell I'd assume he would when preparing. or destroying the horcruxes)

Comment: @Roberto the fake Moody demonstrates it to the whole class using a spider

Comment: @SpacePhoenix You don't learn to cast a spell with just seeing it being cast once by someone else, you know? Much less a powerful and complex spell like the Killing Curse.

Comment: @Roberto any proof of that?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Plenty. If you could learn a spell with just seeing it being cast, classes in Hogwarts would be really simple. Spells have a specific incantation, a concrete wand movement, require concentration and intent, etc. That's why students have to practice spells in their lessons. Harry and Ron usually have to practice a lot to learn spells (in books we see them messing up Windgardium Leviosa, Silencius, the Freeze Charm...)

Comment: I like your explaination. As you pointed out, he tries to cast crucio but gets blocked and Snape comments that "You haven't got the nerve or the ability". Maybe this reminds him of what Bellatrix had said in the last book that you have to really mean a curse like Crucio and even in an extreme rage like this Harry knew he would be unable to cause sufficient pain to Snape. So he changes tactics and casts sectumsempra.